# Convert SVG Files to TTF

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I have a folder full of SVG files that represent each character of the keyboard. They were created using Processing.

I want to create a TTF font from these Svg's. Here is the repo hosting the SVG. 
https://github.com/aswinmohanme/Plexta-FreeFont/tree/master/svg

The SVG's are directly rendered from inside processing. But I cannot important them into FontForge or BirdFont.

FontForge hangs and BirdFont rendered a black Box.

Could someone show how to import them correctly , into either of the given programs. I also have inkscape installed.

Cheers

P.S Comment if you need any more information.

Comment: Any chance we can see the svg of one of the letters. But yes SVG does not guarantee anything it needs to be a very plain svgwith no color and only vector shapes.

Comment: SVG is in the Repo. Select any letter

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded your files and tried to import them in FontForge and encountered some problems during the process:

### Extracting the files

I had some trouble extracting your svg files to my Windows 10 computer. You are using some of the restricted characters: `<>:"/\|?*`. Other systems might have other restricted characters, so instead of naming your files `/.svg` or `:.svg` it would be safer to call them `slash.svg` and `colon.svg` - only use letters and numbers.

### First import in FontForge

Most of the files didn't have that problem though, so I tried to import the "O" in FontForge and it crashed immediately as you are experiencing.

### Analysis in Illustrator

Opening some letters in Illustrator I found some issues you need to fix for FontForge to be able to import the file:

- Your files have a background rectangle. It shouldn't be there.
- Your files consists of lines with a 2 pt stroke. If you import lines into FontForge, make sure your font is a `Stroke Font` (find it in `Element/Font Info/Layers`). If it isn't the strokes will be expanded by FontForge, but your files are very complex so it seems that it can't handle the task. If you want to make an `Outline Font` instead of a `Stroke Font` you could manually expand all the strokes and unite the shapes in Illustrator.
- It seems every line is duplicated on top of itself. You should fix that.
- All the files with non-letter/non-digit names opens up in Illustrator with an `An unknown problem occurred.` error and looks more eroded than the other characters. Furthermore they contain a text object, which shouldn't be there:
  [image: dollarsign]
- But the worst problem is the complexity of your design. Look at this point count:
  [image: point count]
  There are 6324 points in the "O". As mentioned above, half of them are unnecessary, but 3162 points is still quite a lot. Standard fonts might use 10-100 points. After trying to fix some of the issues above, I did manage to import the "O" into FontForge, but when I tried to enter edit mode it crashed. I believe you need to find a way to drastically cut down the number of points in your design, because even if you found a way to make a font of these files the user of the font might experience problems with their application hanging because they just added 3000+ points for each character styled with the font. I like the concept of your font, but maybe it isn't so suitable for a font file. You could still use the letters in other ways.

Comment: Fixed the Text Object issue and The eroded Non letter issue. We could reduce the number of points by combining the entire shape. Right ?

Comment: If all else fails how do you think I should distribute my font ?

Comment: If you want it to be a stroke font you can't really combine them that much. If it is a outline font you can expand the stroke and unite the shapes. But that will give you a higher number of points. I don't know if an outline font is faster or slower than a stroke font. Can't you also tweak the processing code to make the pattern less detailed?

Comment: The complexity of the pattern is it's soul I think I am getting somewhere, will post if I manage to get it to work.

Comment: The complexity of the pattern is its downfall. Fonts aren't meant to have this many points. You would do much better to do a standard glyph, and then use pattern to color the glyph. After all, the shape is still quite pedestrian.

Comment: If font forge crashes, have you tried Glyphs3 app? I got that because it was cheaper  and I've had a lot of success with it for my projects, plus it has plugin capabilities.